# Alternative way to set member to bypass __set

Tags: php

### The Problem:

In the overload method [__set](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) I set members to the same instance. When altering the value to lowercase the method is running twice before the expected behavior is performed.

### The Question:

Is there an alternative way to set a member of the instance to prevent the filter and validation process to run twice after altering the key value?

### The Code:

```
class Foo
{
  public function __construct(array $structure = array())
  {
    $this->extend($structure);
  }

  public function extend(array $structure)
  {
    foreach ($structure as $key => $value)
      $this->$key = $value;
  }

  public function __set($name, $value) 
  {
    if(is_array($value) && $this->isAssoc($value))
      $value = new static($value);

    $key = strtolower($name);
    $this->$key = $value;
  }

  protected function isAssoc(array $array) 
  {
    $keys     = array_keys($array);
    $filtered = array_filter($keys, 'is_string');
    $count    = count($filtered);

    return (bool)$count;
  }
}
```

Comment: why not store in an array property instead of distinct properties directly ? You also could use __get() to abstract the access so the substitution is transparent to the outside.

Comment: @Calimero I did before, but the instance is itteratable and I don't wanna use an IteratorAggregate interface if not necessary. Why? just a cleaner interface, so not the worst if that's the only solution to get around the problem.

Comment: I don't mean this as a criticism, but having a clean interface won't help much if you resort to dirty tricks (only thing on my mind right now to circumvent __set()) to make it work.

Comment: @Calimero Agreed, but there is a use case in my opinion to use the method. The instance is ment as a structure to be used instead of an array. The instance purpose is the same as an stdClass, with the ability to only use lowercase keys.

Comment: Variable (and property) names are case sensitive in PHP, so converting a non lower case string to lower leads to a different property name, this is why php executes __set twice in your case (once for the original name and the second is for the transformed one if there is any difference after the transformation). You can test it by setting a property using lower case name and a non lower case name. As I know there is no other solution than using an embedded storage (like an array or an stdObject instance) to bypass this.

Comment: Additional to the issue is that the __set method is only used for members that doesn't exist. So if you already set the member, the filtration wont take part the second time. So the, by me at least, expected behavior of setting the same member with the same associated attribute as in the code example, the type of the value wouldn't be of the instance Foo, but of an array the second time you set it. My choice became to implement the `Iterator` and `JsonSerializable` interfaces to get the functionalities I was looking for, eg using __set as a filter.